# HTML remove whitespace between the text and border

Tags: html, css

So I'm new to HTML and I'm having trouble with styling my HTML documents. I want to create a box area that has my content in. This is my code so far:

```html
<div style="border:1px solid black; margin:20px 20px;">
    <h3>About Me!</h3>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that theres a gap between the border and the top of the  element. How can I remove this please?

[image: What I mean]

Comment: set padding to 0. Margin will create white space around your border and padding create white space within your border. If thats not working maybe the h3 have a margin on it or a high line height

Comment: @Baracuda078 that didnt do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The all tags have by default margin with. In your case 'h3' tag have (margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;) due to which your upper space is created. 1em = 10px so by reducing it to 5px will help you as shown in below snippet.

```html
<div style="border:1px solid black;">
    <h3 style="margin:5px">About Me!</h3>
    <p  style="margin:5px">Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank You!

Comment: This is just wrong, Adrien's answer is much more accurate.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I understand this better so im gonna use this

Comment: @ZohirSalak its down to personal opinions really as to which is better

Comment: Everyone have a right here to give opinions. So we should appreciate the @ZohirSalak to tell us, what is more good and accurate. By the Thank you legacy Code. have a good day

Comment: This is not a matter of opinion, If this was opinion based the question would've been closed. The question clearly states to remove the space between text and the top border, This answer only tweaks it and so it happens that it works for op, So it obviously doesn't answer the question fully, nor does it explain what that space is. For future readers this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @ZohirSalak you are right. I can edit my post and add more information about it. Thank you for you concerns and contribution. Have a good day.

Answer (score -1):

H3 tag have default margin top value, set it to 0 with css

```
h3{
    margin-top : 0px;
}
```

or with css in style tag

```
<h3 style="margin-top: 0px">Title</h3>
```

But I recomand you to use external css file

Source : [Default css values](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)